# Linux DHCP server vs windows DHCP server

Tags: linux-networking, dhcp-server

I planned to install DHCP server into the Linux or Ubuntu machine for learning purpose, I just want to know difference between them and linux DHCP server suitable for managing 100 to 200 employees in organization.?

Comment: One has a GUI, and yes Linux can be used for large organizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pfsense](https://www.pfsense.org/download/) which has many features to manage DHCP with good GUI, you can do MAC address binding on DHCP so that certain users can get same ip every time and lot more features

You can add many packages like squid,Ntop etc to monitor bandwidth and secure your network

It works great both with cli and GUI, it uses the freeBSD Linux